# Inserting images in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is the proper way to include images in Hybris using `siteResourcePath` or `<theme:image>`

In what cases should we use in each of them?

If we are using `<theme:image>` should we mention the property in `theme-alpha-deskptop_en.properties`?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the proper way to include images in Hybris using
>   siteResourcePath or <theme:image>?

Both are used to display the static image or a content. siteResourcePath, themeResourcePath, and other ResourcePath are used to get the static contents like CSS, image, font, js etc.

> In what cases should we use in each of them?

Let say you want to show the static image on some page with regardless of your theme, site, lang. which means it's common for all, so you can simply use siteResourcePath or commonResourcePath(based on your folder-structure).

```
<img src="${commonResourcePath}/images/my_image_300x300.jpg" alt="My Image" title="My Image" />
```

Now, in another scenario where you have to display different static image based on your theme/site/lang, so here you can declare a respective value in each properties files and pass the code to `<theme:image>`. value of respective file has peeked. Like missingProductImage.

```
<theme:image code="img.missingProductImage.responsive.product" alt="${fn:escapeXml(product.name)}" title="${fn:escapeXml(product.name)}"/>
```

*theme-alpha-desktop_de.properties*

`img.missingProductImage.responsive.product=/_ui/responsive/theme-alpha/images/missing_product_DE_300x300.jpg`

*theme-black-desktop_en.properties*

`img.missingProductImage.responsive.product=/_ui/responsive/theme-black/images/missing_product_EN_300x300.jpg`

> If we are using  should we mention the property in
>   theme-alpha-deskptop_en.properties?

As I mentioned in above example, if you are using `<theme:image>` then you have to mention a respective value in all respective properties files (not only in theme-alpha-deskptop_en.properties). Which are based on your theme, UI experience, and supportive language.

---

```
    final String siteRootUrl = contextPath + "/_ui/" + uiExperienceCodeLower;
    final String sharedResourcePath = contextPath + "/_ui/" + SHARED;
    final String siteResourcePath = siteRootUrl + "/site-" + siteName;
    final String themeResourcePath = siteRootUrl + "/theme-" + themeName;
    final String commonResourcePath = siteRootUrl + "/" + COMMON;
```

[image]